# ¿Cómo recorrer una lista para saber cuantas veces se repite cada elemento en una columna?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Necesito recorrer una lista y devolver cuantas veces se repite cada elemento de la lista en una columna específica de un csv.

```
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd

def findhashtags(a):
    with open(a, 'r') as out:
        contenido = out.read()
        climatehashtags = re.findall(r"#climate\w+", contenido, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Con esta función consigo la lista requerida. El csv tiene las líneas con el formato
'sentiment, message, tweetid'

Estaba pensando en separar la columna 1 (message) con split y luego recorrerlo, pero realmente no si es imposible ni como implementarlo.

Soy nuevo estudiando así que agradezco cualquier tipo de consejos y ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: La variable `content` no está definida.

Comment: Quería hacer referencia a la variable "contenido", ya lo he editado.

Comment: La función `read()` lee todo el contenido del archivo y te devuelve un solo string. No es una lista ni tiene columnas.

Comment: Agregando a lo que dice Candid Moe, NUNCA uses split para dividir el contenido de un csv, ya que una linea como `'"a";"b;c"'.split(";")` te devolvería `['"a"', '"b', 'c"']`. Por que no usas alguno de los modulos que importaste para leer el csv (como Pandas o csv)?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes hacer un ciclo `for` y obtener la suma de cada una de las palabras deseadas en tu lista

Ejemplo:

```
filter = ['#climate', 'health']
d = {}
for word in filter:
    d[word] = df[df['message'].str.lower().str.contains(word)]['message'].str.contains(word).sum()
print(d)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
{'#climate': 1417, 'health': 426}
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es obtener todas las filas que contengan cualquiera de las palabras en tu lista podrías hacer un `join` de las palabras y utilizarlo como argumento en el método `contains()`

```
filter = ['#climate', 'health']
df[df['message'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(filter))]
```